# Octave Matrices: Why are these two costfunctions acting differently?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, octave

Knowing that X is a mx3 matrix and theta is a 3x1 matrix, I calculated the cost function of logistic regression as follows:

```
h = sigmoid(theta'*X');
J = ((-y)*log(h)-(1-y)*log(1-h))/m;

grad(1) = (h'-y)'*X(:,1);
grad(2) = (h'-y)'*X(:,2);
grad(3) = (h'-y)'*X(:,3);
```

The output is the picture attached:

[image: 1]

That's explicitly not the correct result.

When I do

```
h = sigmoid(X*theta);
J = ((-y)'*log(h)-(1-y)'*log(1-h))/m;

grad = (X'*(h - y))/m;
```

I get the right result:

[image: correctoutput]

For me, these two codes are the same - and yes, I checked the matrices sizes in the first code.

Could somebody help me understand while one is giving one input and the other a different output? Somehow, the first code is giving lots of cost at theta values...

Comment: What is `y` here? Please [edit] your question to make your example into a [mcve] so we can reproduce this result. I'm sure that by debugging you will see somewhere that the various stages of transposition cease being equivalent somewhere - try creating intermediate variables instead of doing all of the maths inline, then you can determine the precise point where the differences happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're not paying attention to the dimensionality of your inputs and outputs. (which in turn is because your code is not properly commented/structured.). Assuming y has the same orientation as X in terms of observations, then:

In the first case you have:

```
h = sigmoid(theta'*X');               # h is a 1xm horizontal vector
J = ((-y)*log(h)-(1-y)*log(1-h))/m;   # J is an mxm matrix
```

In the second case you have:

```
h = sigmoid(X*theta);                   # h is an mx1 vector
J = ((-y)'*log(h)-(1-y)'*log(1-h))/m;   # J is a 1xm horizontal vector
```

This is also the reason you get multiple printouts of that "Cost at test theta" printout. My guess is you're calling "sum" somewhere down the line, to sum over m observations, but because J was an mxm matrix instead of a vector, you ended up with a vector in an fprintf statement, which has the effect of printing that statement as many times as there are elements in your vector. Is m=12 by any chance?